# Finding simple modules of semisimple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following algebras are semisimple? For each, find all their simple modules:

• $A_1 := k[x]/(x^2 − 4)$ (assuming that $2 \ne 0 ∈ k);$

• $A_2 := \mathbb C[x]/(x^3 − x^2 + x − 1) \text{ and } A_2 := \mathbb Q[x]/(x^3 − x^2 + x − 1)$

• $A_3 := \mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$

Obviously if I can find simple modules then the algebras are semisimple I just don't know how to find them. I know that the simple A-modules are up to isomorphism the A-modules $K[X]/(h)$ where h is a irreducible polynomial that divides f.

Would it then be appropriate to factor each polynomial and express the algebras as these factorisations?

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously if I can find simple modules then the algebras are semisimple

Hm?  Every ring has simple modules... what would that prove about semisimplicity?  Do you mean showing the ring is a sum of simple ideals?

> I know that the simple A-modules are up to isomorphism the A-modules []/(ℎ) where h is a irreducible polynomial that divides f.

Excellent! This is indeed useful.

> Would it then be appropriate to factor each polynomial and express the algebras as these factorisations?

Yes.

---

Let me give you an example other than the ones you're working on that will help you get some intuition.

Consider $n=2^3*3^2*5$.  In $\mathbb Z$, there are three maximal ideals containing $n$: $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(5)$, and these correspond exactly to the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Their intersection is $(2*3*5)=(30)$, so the Jacobson radical of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not zero, and the ring is not semisimple. Do you see a suggestive relationship between $2^3*3^2*5$ and $2*3*5$?

Another thing that could have been noticed is that $2*3*5$ is obviously a nonzero nilpotent element, and in a commutative ring, the nilpotent elements all have to be contained in the Jacobson radical. Commutative semisimple rings of course, have a zero radical, so that is another way to see it is not semisimple.

I'm pretty sure the paragraphs above will enable you to immediately spot what the Jacobson radical of a quotient of a PID is in every case, including the ones you posed in your problem. Do you see the pattern?